# java Unknown host exception android

Tags: android, httprequest

hi guys i'm trying to connect to my web page on server. i have checked my code there are no mistakes in it and it works on the emulator but i get force close on the actual device and the in log it says unknown host exception. did any one else run into this.

Error in http connectionjava.net.UnknownHostException: my.url.com

```
    try{

     HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://my.url.com/test/stock.php");
     httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
     HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
     HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
     is = entity.getContent();
     }catch(Exception e){
         Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }
```

Comment: This might be a simple firewall issue. Check whether you can get to http://my.url.com/test/stock.php from the device's browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, do a quick sanity check and make sure you can hit that URL from your device using the browser. If not, then you have a wifi/connection issue on your device.

If you have no issue hitting the URL from the browser, make sure you have the correct permission set in your Android manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: i had wifi issue on device. i wasn't checking if wifi was on or not.